# CloudKit JS via node: Cannot register for notifications

Tags: python, ios, node.js, icloud, cloudkit

I'm trying to interact with my CloudKit database using node.js and Apple's CloudKit.js. I was successfully able to create a server-to-server key and I can use the program to add, remove or edit records. Adding subscriptions also works. Now I wanted it to watch for notifications and print a line when receiving one. However, enabling notifications fails for me. The callback I am trying to register also doesn't get called.

No matter how often I call `registerForNotifications()` on my container, when printing the property `isRegisteredForNotifications`, I always receive `false`.

I come from a "desktop/mobile/native/embedded" centered background concerning programming languages, so the whole world of node.js, JavaScript, promises and especially the `.then()` syntax is still a little foreign to me.

This is the code I am trying to use to receive notifications:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";


var fetch = require('node-fetch');

var CloudKit = require('./cloudkit');
var containerConfig = require('./config');

// A utility function for printing results to the console.
var println = function(key,value) {
    console.log("--> " + key + ":");
    console.log(value);
    console.log();
};

//CloudKit configuration
CloudKit.configure({
    services: {
        fetch: fetch,
        logger: console
    },
    containers: [ containerConfig ]
});


var container = CloudKit.getDefaultContainer();
var database = container.publicCloudDatabase; // We'll only make calls to the public database.

// Sign in using the keyID and public key file.
container.setUpAuth();

function renderNotification(notification) {
  console.log('Got notification!')
};
CloudKit.getDefaultContainer().registerForNotifications();
CloudKit.getDefaultContainer().addNotificationListener(renderNotification);
console.log(CloudKit.getDefaultContainer().isRegisteredForNotifications); // Why does this print false?
```

Even when creating a new subscription and adding a callback using `.then()`, which calls `addNotificationListener`, the property still says `false` and `renderNotification` never gets called.

Is this a bug in Apple's CloudKit JS or am I doing something wrong?

Also, I wanted to mention I was able to successfully accomplish the same tasks (creating, editing, removing records or subscriptions) using the JSON API which I wrapped in Python ([here](https://github.com/Longhanks/PyCloudKit/blob/master/pycloudkit.py)). However, there seems to be no way of receiving notifications of subscriptions, which is why I am trying to use node.js and Apple's CloudKit.js here. If I am missing something here and receiving notifications is actually possible using neither CloudKit.js nor the Cocoa APIs, I would gladly take any advice on how to do so.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can register for notifications and wait for it to be done:

```js
container.addNotificationListener(renderNotification);
container.registerForNotifications()
   .then(function() {
       console.log(container.isRegisteredForNotification) //should be true
   })
   .catch(function(error) {
       console.error('there was an error:', error);
   })
```

Having said that, you can also use the WS endpoints and to make the required calls (e.g. with python). It might be still worthwhile to get your nodejs approach up and running so you can inspect the network calls.

The relevant documentation for working with notifications via WS is here:

- Create Tokens: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/CreateTokens/CreateTokens.html
- Register Tokens:
  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/RegisterTokens/RegisterTokens.html

Comment: there was an error: { [Error: no auth method found]
  _ckErrorCode: 'AUTHENTICATION_FAILED', hmm now what?

Comment: @malhal did you solve it? Getting the same error message right this moment

Comment: @doplumi no sorry I didn’t

Comment: I'm having the same problem. This answer isn't very helpful. First of all, `registerForNotifications` isn't a promise but a regular method. It is not `isRegisteredForNotification` but `isRegisteredForNotifications`. And last but not least: it doesn't solve the problem. Anyone know how to solve this or is it a bug in the API?